# Basic matrix math in R

Tags: r, math, matrix

So I want to perform basic math using two matrices.

As my input I have two 3x3 matrices. I would like to divide every integer in matrixA by every integer in matrixB and the output to be one 3x3 matrix of their products.

What is the R function(s) that can do that for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does matrixB contain zeros?

Comment: Regardless, why not just use the standard `/` operator? It works elementwise, and division by zero becomes `Inf`.

Comment: Does the standard operator divide each integer in matA by matB and create an equal-dimension matrix as an output? Sorry about the noob question.

Comment: It does. Try it out with a few simple examples and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to divide element by element. In this case, you can simply use the `/` operator.

```
### Create two matrices
matA <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
matB <- matA

### Divide element by element
matB / matA

### As Frank pointed out, division by 0 goes to Inf
matA[1, 1] <- 0
matB / matA
```

Comment: Sounds more like OP wants the courage to try some simple experiments for herself.